# Routinely updating a git repo from a large svn repo - how do git svn fetch and git svn rebase differ?

Tags: git, svn

I have a large active SVN repository (40GB+, 35,000+ revisions).  It has a non-standard layout, thousands of branches, and regularly accumulates new branches.

I have a secondary git repository, which I am trying to keep synchronized with the SVN repository.  The git repository exists ONLY to maintain a faithful copy of the revision history from SVN.  The git repository is never interactively used and never accumulates content save from the SVN repository.

It seems clear that repeatedly invoking "git svn fetch" will eventually do what I want.  However - while "git svn fetch" doesn't re-create anything from SVN - which is already present in git - internally, "git svn fetch" takes a very long time to figure out what's done and where it left off.

I've been watching .git/svn/.metadata - and I see that "git svn fetch" works through the entire history of SVN revisions in order to figure out where it left off.  For a large repository like mine - it takes "git svn fetch" many hours to get back to where the fetch stopped - after which it resumes the process of bringing content from SVN to the git repo.

When I try to find out quicker ways to update a git repo with new content from SVN - I sometimes see references suggesting use of "git svn rebase".  However - if "git svn rebase" did what I think I need - the "git svn fetch" command would be superfluous (perhaps after picking up an initial priming SVN revision?).  The use of "rebase" also seems like it's in the context of a git working state.

I must be mistaken in some important way(s) about the relative function of "git svn fetch" and "git svn rebase".  How are these operations different?

Comment: A "faithful copy of the revision history from SVN"? Does this mean that you do not trust SVN? I do not understand why you sync SVN repository to git.

Comment: Our local development environment is based on SVN (and there are good reasons why we chose SVN instead of git).  We recently became subject to a corporate requirement to submit our work to an off-site/disaster-recovery group that insists on maintaining the same content in a git repository.

Answer (score 1):

I still don't know how fetch differs from rebase.  However - what was driving me was the need to incrementally update SVN to git in a reasonable amount of time (without revisiting all the SVN revisions in history - before arriving at versions not yet present in the git repo).

It does appear that this can be done with "git svn fetch" - but you need to add "--revision START:END".  Where START is the last SVN revision added to the git repo and END is the latest version in SVN.  This seemed to me curious - because the documentation for "git svn fetch" does not report "--revision" as an option.

Also reported to be important - use of "--log-window=N".  Where N is a value of the order of 10000 or 20000.

Performance is still disappointing - but seems more hopeful.